# Making local Spring Boot REST API available to global internet

Tags: spring-boot, rest, tcp, ip, router

I have a simple REST API

[image]

and now I want to make an open server using my PC.
That is, I want people from outside my local network to access the API.
I already mapped a port on my router to 8082 (it's available).
But whenever I send a POST request using my external white IP address and 8082 port the request fails.
Is it possible to host your own PC as a server without using third party platforms like Heroku?
I mean, what am I doing wrong?
The idea is: my router should receive a request to <global_ip_address>:8082 and forward it to my controller. What is so difficult about it?